# How to convert certain columns to separate rows, and repeat all other contents for different rows with same index

Tags: python, pandas

The present data frame:

```
Office|Room|Empno.1|Empname.1|Desig.1|...|Empno.3|Empname.3|Desig.3|HRA|DA|BASIC
```

201|1|001|John|Analyst|...|003|Harry|Engineer|5000|4000|12000

I want to keep Office and Room as index, and HRA, DA and BASIC as constant but make three separate rows for empname.1, empname.2 and empname.3 with associated details i.e., empno, desig.

```
Expected data frame:
Office|Room|Empno|Empname|Desig|HRA|DA|BASIC

201|1|001|John|Analyst|5000|4000|12000
.....
201|1|003|Harry|Engineer|5000|4000|12000
.....
```

Comment: Is Empno.* a unique identifier ? Or is it possible that Empno.1 has the same value as Empno.2 for the same Office and Room ?

Comment: no, Empno.1 does not have the same value as Empno.2 for the same Office and Room. @SmileyProd

Comment: are you reading the data from a CSV file?

Comment: yes, I am reading a CSV file. @mohanys

Answer (score 0):

make use of `usecols` Parameter of the `pd.read_csv` to read the data into multiple dataframes like below (for example).

```
df= pd.read_csv("ThisFile.csv", usecols=[1,3])
```

This will load only the second and fourth columns into the data DataFrame.

Then, when you have multiple data frames, you set the columns of the all the Dataframes as same with

```
df1.columns = df2.columns = df3.columns =  ['Office','Room','Empno', 'Empname','Desig','HRA','DA','BASIC']
```

and then concatenate the dataframes

```
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
```

Comment: what if, we were to modify the data frame itself to get the desired format? is it possible? I want the Office, Room, DA, HRA, BASIC columns to be the same, getting repeated thrice for different employees @mohanys

Comment: This kinda helps but would be really nice if at all it can be done in a bit more simpler way since the size of the data can be huge then making separate data frames will be time-consuming :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Below is the example of how it works.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a1': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
               'b1': ["1:00","2:00","3:00"],
               'c1': ["Apple", "Orange", "Apple"],
               'a2': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
               'b2': ["4:00","5:00","6:00"],
               'c2': ["Apple", "Orange", "Apple"],
               'a3': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
               'b3': ["7:00","8:00","9:00"],
               'c3': ["Apple", "Orange", "Apple"]})
```

dataframe is as below to begin with

```
a1  b1      c1      a2   b2     c2      a3  b3      c3
A1  1:00    Apple   A1  4:00    Apple   A1  7:00    Apple
A2  2:00    Orange  A2  5:00    Orange  A2  8:00    Orange
A3  3:00    Apple   A3  6:00    Apple   A3  9:00    Apple
```

Then we run the below code,

```
a=df.shape[1]
out={}
def split_df(x):
    for i in range(3):
        out[i] = x.iloc[:,i*a//3:(i+1)*a//3]    
    return out
split_df(df)
for i in range(3):
    out[i].columns = ['a','b','c']
df_oriented=pd.concat([out[0],out[1],out[2]])
df_oriented
```

the result is as below

```
a   b       c
A1  1:00    Apple
A2  2:00    Orange
A3  3:00    Apple
A1  4:00    Apple
A2  5:00    Orange
A3  6:00    Apple
A1  7:00    Apple
A2  8:00    Orange
A3  9:00    Apple
```